# How to get the teams user details without accessing the bot

Tags: c#, .net, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

Is there any method or new features available in teams to get new user details without accessing the particular bot?

Comment: Could you please provide more details on your ask? Are you trying to get user details of your tenant?

Comment: Please refer [Get single member details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#get-single-member-details)

Comment: Whenever bot is installed on Teams, would we get the user details from the OnMembersAddedAsync without having a conversation with bot?@Prasad-MSFT
@RithwikBojja-MT

Comment: No, A member added event is sent to your bot in the following scenarios:

-When the bot, itself, is installed and added to a conversation
-When a user is added to a conversation where the bot is installed

Comment: @ANNAJMOYALAN -  If a user install the bot and it calls the OnMembersAddedAsync () method, you can get the user details from the TurnContext object like turnContext.Activity.From.Name etc.   Reference sample link: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/app-complete-sample/csharp/template-bot-master-csharp/Bot/DialogBot.cs

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility of implementing roaster to grab the user details like user ID and object ID based on the azure active directory. We can get the information based on the number of entries per page minimum to 50 count users. The type of information we can get is like when the user log in into the system and what are the operations done by the user based on the name ID.

**Python:**

```
async def _show_members(
    self, turn_context: TurnContext
):
    members = await TeamsInfo.get_team_members(turn_context)
}
```

Credit: [surbhigupta](https://github.com/surbhigupta)